# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: at retrofit2.Utils.methodError

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have the following code :

```
@GET("findByPin?pincode={pin}&date={dt}")
Call<CentreStats> getCentreStats(@Query("pin") String pin, @Query("dt") String dt);
```

And I' getting this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "pincode={pin}&date={dt}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above syntax is not correct. Replace your code with this

```
@GET("findByPin")
Call<CentreStats> getCentreStats(@Query("pincode") String pin, @Query("date") String dt);
```